# Use of postfix/prefix expressions

Tags: java, algorithm

I understand in prefix/postfix, there is no need to bother about precedence of operators.
But where do we use prefix/postfix expressions?
Are they internally converted by the compiler? 
Is there a way I could write expression in prefix/postfix and the compiler evaluates it for me?

Comment: I really can't understand what you're asking. Those kinds of expressions are like any other expression: you use them when you think it's a good idea to use them, the compiler compiles them to byte code, and they're evaluated at runtime.

Comment: I mean, in my code can I write prefix/postfix expressions involving more than 2 operators?

Comment: Again, I don't understand what you mean. How about trying, or at least showing us what your mean with **code**? The compiler won't destroy the computer if it doesn't compile. It will tell you that it does, or doesn't compile. And then you'll know.

Comment: Are you talking about prefix/postfix operator such as `x++` or about postfix notation (e.g. Reverse-Polish notation) such as `* 5 + 3 4`?

Comment: Yes I mean the Reverse-Polish notation.
I have never seen people writing like this(* 5 + 3 4?) in the code.

Comment: @Priya I don't think you can write expression in Reverse-Polish notation in Java, it would be very unlikely. Do you have any example?

Comment: Java doesn't support those kinds of expressions.

Comment: If you are writing an infix expression (fully parenthesize) which is to be converted into postfix with maximum two operands and one operator into 1 bracket example: ((a+b)*c) then you don't need operator precedence but when the case is different like (a+b)*c-d/f, in this case operator precedence is needed.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Ff you're actually talking about postfix (RPN) notation, then no, the compiler uses infix notation for expressions. You could write an algorithm that converts an RPN expression into an infix expression, try [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_to_infix_conversion)

Postfix and prefix operators are just like a binary operator, but they work on only one operand.

Postfix increment (the increment occurs after the variable is evaluated):

```
int x = 1;
int y = x++; // y = 1 but after the assignment occurs x = 2
int z = x; // z = 2
```

Prefix increment:

```
int x = 1;
int y = ++x; // y = 2 and before the assignment occurs x = 2
int z = x; // z = 2
```

The rules that apply to the increment operator also apply to the decrement operator.

Prefix NOT (inverts a boolean expression):

```
boolean a = true;
boolean b = !a; // b = false, a = true
```

I think I have understood the question correctly, but I'm not sure what you mean about the compiler "evaluating" them "for you".

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that prefix and postfix operations and notations are mostly useful for theories these days, but they have been used "for real". See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29, http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_dc.htm, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Hewlett-Packard

Answer (score 0):

Few languages use postfix notation (the only one I know of would be PostScript), but the resulting CPU instructions would be the same as for infix notation:

```
a = (3 + 4) * 5
```

or

```
a = * + 3 4 5
```

Would be converted (in an imaginary, very simple, instruction sets):

```
add r0 3 4   # r0 =  3 + 4
mul r1 r0 5  # r1 = r0 * 5
```

Your CPU does not care about the initial notation, all it accepts is a set of « basic » instructions, so the compiler has to convert the notation you use to instructions understandable by your CPU.